# declare static member without definition

Tags: c++, static, linker

class `A` declares static variable `b`, but there is **NO** definition of `b` in the code.

Result:

1. The code can run successfully.
2. There is no output. So the code do not call the constructor and destructor of `b`.

My question:

1. when class `A` declares `b`, how to find `b's` definition?
2. why the code can run successfully?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

class B
{
public:
    B()
    {
        std::cout << "go into B constructor" << std::endl;
    };


    B::~B()
    {
        std::cout << "go into B destructor" << std::endl;
    };


    void output()
    {
        std::cout << "B output" << std::endl;
    }
};

class A
{
public:
    static B b;
    int i;
};

//B A::b;
int main()
{
    A a;
//    A::b.output();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ODR violations are generally NDR (non diagnostic required). linker used to complain only when used.

Comment: There is something called as `ODR` read it.

Comment: `b` is not ODR-used here so no definition is required. It is similar to declaring a bunch of functions and never invoking them - their definitions are not required.

Answer (score 2):

In this code `A::b` is not used at all, so **no** definition **needed**:

```
int main()
{
    A a;
    return 0;
}
```

In this code `A::b` is used, so definition of A::b is **needed**:

```
 int main()
 {
    A::b.output();
    return 0;
 }
```

Fot **non-const static data member** to be initialized, this has to be done explicitly, for example add `B A::b` after class A {... }:

```
class A
{
public:
    static B b; // declaration of A::b
    int i;
};

B A::b; // definition of A::b
```

[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/964494f6d44c0b9b)